# Instead of "Data Row 0", "Data Row 1" etc. Output a custom name

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, tfs

In Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013, I'm using the Unit Testing Framework. Specifically, I'm using data-driven testing that will read from an XML file.

## The gist of my question

Here's some sample code:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public class DataDrivenTestingClass{
   public TestContext TestContext{get; set;}

   [TestMethod]
   [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "test.xml", "XMLTests", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
   public void MyOnlyDataDrivenTestFromXML(){
      var testName = TestContext.DataRow[0].ToString();
      //... blah blah blah other logic
      //<snip>
      Assert.IsTrue(true); //of course this is not what I really do
   }
}
```

And the output will come out like this:

> Test Passed - MyOnlyDataDrivenTestFromXML (Data Row 0) 
> Test Passed - MyOnlyDataDrivenTestFromXML (Data Row 1) 
> Test Passed - ... 
> Test Passed - MyOnlyDataDrivenTestFromXML (Data Row N)

Clearly, `(Data Row i)` is not very descriptive. The XML stores the name I'd like to use instead (I could use anything else, but already having it in the xml seems convenient). I'm not sure this is possible, though.

---

## Other information, speculation

The problem is that, while you can get the test name from `TestContext` via `TestContext.TestName`, you cannot set it. Also, you cannot (should not) simply inherit from `TestContext` and make one that allows you to do so.

I've also tried to set the name directly from the `Properties` of `TestContext` like so, but without success:

```
TestContext.Properties["TestName"] = testName;
TestContext.Properties["FullyQualifiedTestClassName"] = testName;
```

What's out of the question is having the tests output to a .trx file, and then post-processing that. This is because the tests are run on a build server backed by a SQL Server. There are no test logs that I will output.

If all else fails, I believe this is possible by hooking into the [TFS Web Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) and writing a service that queries test results and does an edit there, but I'd rather not go this route if at all possible.

Another thing I was thinking was that it might be possible to do some kind of generic programming, templated approach that will evaluate to all the appropriate test names at compile-time, but this seems both very difficult and overkill.

---

### Is this doable?

---

Related (but without answer): [MSTest data driven Test set DisplayName for Rows from DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924659/mstest-data-driven-test-set-displayname-for-rows-from-datasource)

Comment: Can't you set `TestContext.Properties` values all you want?  Barring that, can't you just get a useful column out of the `DataRow`?

Comment: @ebyrob: I've tried saying `TestContext.Properties["TestName"] = ...;` and `TestContext.Properties["FullyQualifiedTestClassName"] = ...;` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @ebyrob: can you speak more about what you mean in the second sentence?

Comment: I was thinking your code sample was part of the test emitter, it's just the test-case, so you won't be able to change what it writes out so easily.  There is a way to control this.  You may have to over-ride GetName() or something like that.

Comment: Wow, so much for over-riding.  I wrote a wrapper for `TestContext` that allowed `TestName` to change, but the framework never reads the `TestContext.TestName` after setting it.  Ugh.  Tough one.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like this would work better as a comment more than an answer, but alas I do not have enough reputation.

There is a similar question with an answer here: [Mstest name instead Data Row with Data-Driven testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284816/mstest-name-instead-data-row-with-data-driven-testing)

It looks like they do TestContext.WriteLine() to get the values they want printed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This looks useful. What we'd ultimately like is for the test name in our TFS database to be named properly rather than generating our own report.